# Printing bitmaps in C# - hasmorepages issue

Tags: c#, printing

right now, I am trying to print a few bitmaps I am saving in a form. I have 3 I am generating, but when I am printing them out, it only prints out 1.

This is my print code.

```
private void PrintDoc_PrintPage(Object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
int bound1 = 0;
int bound2 = 0;
float boundsH = e.Graphics.VisibleClipBounds.Height;
float boundsW = e.Graphics.VisibleClipBounds.Width;
float boundsS = e.PageBounds.Height;
float boundsE = e.PageBounds.Width;
float CBound1 = boundsS - boundsH;
float CBound2 = boundsE - boundsW;
float boundHD = (boundsH - CBound1);
float boundHW = (boundsW - CBound2);
int bounds1 = Convert.ToInt32(boundHD);
int bounds2 = Convert.ToInt32(boundHW);
int check1 = ((bounds1 * 100) / OverPanel.Height);
int check2 = ((bounds2 * 100) / OverPanel.Width);
if (check1 < check2)
{
bound1 = (OverPanel.Height * check1) / 100;
bound2 = (OverPanel.Width * check1) / 100;
}
else
{
bound1 = (OverPanel.Height * check2) / 100;
bound2 = (OverPanel.Width * check2) / 100;
}
e.Graphics.DrawImage(AllPrints[0], 0, 0, bound2, bound1);
e.HasMorePages = true;
e.Graphics.DrawImage(AllPrints[1], 0, 0, bound2, bound1);
e.HasMorePages = true;
e.Graphics.DrawImage(AllPrints[2], 0, 0, bound2, bound1);
e.HasMorePages = false;
AllPrints[0].Save("C:/Test/1.bmp");
AllPrints[1].Save("C:/Test/2.bmp");
AllPrints[2].Save("C:/Test/3.bmp");[/CODE]

This code draws 1, 2 and 3 on the page for me to test my prints with.

[CODE]private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
for (Locc = 1; Locc <= 3; Locc++)
{
label1.Text = Locc.ToString();
WholePage();
ClearPage();
}
}
}
PrintDocument PrintDoc = new PrintDocument();
PrintDoc.PrintPage += PrintDoc_PrintPage;
PrintDoc.Print();
}[/CODE]

This code saves the prints

[CODE]public void WholePage()
{
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int width = OverPanel.Width;
int height = OverPanel.Height;
Rectangle Rec = new Rectangle(0,0,width,height);
PImage = new Bitmap(OverPanel.Width, OverPanel.Height);
OverPanel.DrawToBitmap(PImage, Rec);
AllPrints.Add(new Bitmap(PImage, PImage.Size));
}
```

Everything else but the print is working properly. The print only prints the last page, but it saves and loads from the list properly. I end up with 3 bitmaps in my C:/Test drive with label1 reading 1, 2 and 3 respectively. But it only prints out page#3 with label1 reading 3.

Some help with hasmorepages, I tried googling and it seems this is the exact code on MSDN and a bunch of people use so I'm lost.

Comment: Whenever I see "this seems to be exact code on MSDN and a bunch of people use it so I'm lost" I can only read that as "I am relying on code that I don't understand to do magic for me so I don't need to understand what it's doing". This isn't much help to you, but my point is, if you can't say what it's doing, then you aren't going to be able to do any effective troubleshooting, and that's going to limit how well you're able to ask for help.

Comment: The code is also somewhat borked. I tried reformatting it so it reads better, but I found you have unmatched curly braces...

Answer (score 1):

as you can read on MSDN your print_page handler is supposed to deliver one page at a time to the graphics object in the event args ...

since you draw all 3 images ontop of each other, the last one survives, and is printed

since at the end of your event handler HasMorePages is false, your handler is not called again to print the next page ...

so the machine won't do what you want ... it will just follow your instructions ...